# "TLS wrong version number" with OpenSSL 1.1.1

Tags: curl, openssl, docker-registry, docker-api, tls1.3

I try to use [Docker Registry REST API V2](https://docs.docker.com/registry/spec/api/) on a local Registry instance.

Run Registry: `docker run -d --network host --name registry registry:2` ([docs](https://docs.docker.com/registry/deploying/)).

Command for checking Registry:

```
$ curl https://localhost:5000/v2/_ping
curl: (35) error:1408F10B:SSL routines:ssl3_get_record:wrong version number
```

My curl uses OpenSSL 1.1.1 which should support TLS 1.3. But it doens't work:

```
$ curl -3 https://localhost:5000/v2/_ping
curl: (4) OpenSSL was built without SSLv3 support
```

Curl and OpenSSL versions:

```
$curl --version
curl 7.64.0 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.64.0 OpenSSL/1.1.1
Release-Date: 2019-02-06
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: AsynchDNS IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL TLS-SRP UnixSockets HTTPS-proxy
```

OS: Linux Mint 19.1

OpenSSL 1.1.1 is installed according to [guide](https://websiteforstudents.com/manually-install-the-latest-openssl-toolkit-on-ubuntu-16-04-18-04-lts/).

Does OpenSSL 1.1.1 support TLS 1.3? How to fix this issue?

Comment: Instead of `-3` try option `--tlsv1.3`.

Comment: This still seems to be an issue in October 2022... Tried with the latest version of registry from docker hub.

Answer (score 2):

the webserver you have running on localhost:5000 is so old that it's trying to use SSLv3, and SSLv3 support has been disabled-by-default since libcurl 7.39.0 from 2014, your curl version is newer than 7.39.0.

update your webserver or disable encryption entirely, using SSLv3 today gives a false sense of security.